# Unable to run Gala window manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-managers

I'm Elementary OS Luna (Ubuntu-based) user, and trying to do some tweaks I installed Gnome Tweaks Tool. After installing and running it, my computer got several problems.

All the windows were without borders and titlebars. Couldn't close, minimize, resize etc. I could solve it by running Compix and putting it as startup. But some good features of Elementary OS does not work with Compix, but just with Gala. And when I try to run Gala, this happens:

```
jefs@JefsPC:~$ gala --replace
(some css warnings, okey)
(gala:6103): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.mutter' does not contain a key named 'center-new-windows'
Trace/breakpoint trap
jefrey@JefsPC:~$ _
```

I tried reinstalling elementary-desktop, removing gnome-tweaks-tool, reinstalling gala, installing and removing mutter and even going to /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.mutter.gschema.xml and putting that "center-new-windows" key manually, then restarting my computer. It made that key to show up on dconf editor, but Gala still not detecting it...

Is there something I can do to get Gala back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade